# Can't scroll down when using custom alert

Tags: html, css

I created custom modal with css :

```
.backdrop{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    z-index: 50;
}

.modal-box{
    position: fixed;
    top: 5vh;
    left: 30vw;
    width: 40vw;
    padding: 16px;
    z-index: 100;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

when the modal is too high i cant access to the bottom of the model.
which property I  missing ?

[image]

Comment: It will be good to see the snippet or jsfiddle.

Comment: Try removing `height: 100%` in `.backdrop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `position: fixed` is screen fixed.. 
So, If you want to scroll, You have to change `fixed` -> `absolute`.

Answer (score 0):

Your modal's height is longer than the viewport.

Add a bottom attribute to prevent its height to go under the fold and add an overflow attribute so you can scroll within the modal.

```
bottom: 5vh;
overflow: auto;
```